# bootstrap justify-content-between not working in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, justify

i'm trying to make a header that when on pc is a normal nav and when on a smaller device (like phone etc.) becomes a burger nav. now the burger nav is working (only need to make it so that whenever I get on a smaller device it gets shown and the other one gets d-none)

now the problem is with my normal nav, whenever I try to justify content between so that the links space out evenly it just doenst wanna work and I get default block display

here's the code that needs fixing:

```
<div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
            <div class="burger-nav d-none">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <h1 id="logo"><span class="h1yellow">Crypto</span><span class="h1white">Mania</span></h1>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="normal-nav d-flex justify-content-between"> <!-- this part doesnt work -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <h1 id="logo"><span class="h1yellow">Crypto</span><span class="h1white">Mania</span></h1>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

this is the whole nav but I put a little comment where the problem is. If anyone sees anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar-light">
            <div class="burger-nav d-none">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <h1 id="logo"><span class="h1yellow">Crypto</span><span class="h1white">Mania</span></h1>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="I removed this classes "> <!-- this part doesnt work -->
                <ul class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <h1 id="logo"><span class="h1yellow">Crypto</span><span class="h1white">Mania</span></h1>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Try This code please.

Comment: this works... i don't realy understand why though, could you explain?

Comment: nvm figured it out it was the navbar-nav class on the ul which overrides the display

Comment: some classes had flex-direction : column in them